# How to create a segue to a Table View Controller Scene directly in a swift class file?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue, facebook-login

I am implementing FB Login.  I have instantiated the `FBSDKLoginButton()` and added it to view directly from my ViewController.swift file (created and presented through the source code).

Normally I present a view modally by dragging and connecting the button to the new view in Interface Builder.  However this button does not exist in my storyboard.  How can I complete this task, but directly from my ViewController.swift file.

Comment: so you need to push to another viewController programmatically in your button click??

Answer (score 3):

You can add manual segues from one `ViewController` to other `ViewController`.

In your `FirstViewController` in `storyboard` :

[image]

Connect the `segue`.

Then select the connected `segue` and add `Identifier`:

[image]

Now you can use:

```
self.navigationController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: <The Identifier name>, sender: <If you want to send some data with it>)
```

you can use `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

}
```

to send data to the `SecondViewCntroller`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Direct segue needs a connection from UI object to other view-controller. Rather segue, you can use `pushViewController`:

[image]

```
let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
if let viewcontroller = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "storyboardIdentifier") as? YourViewController {
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewcontroller, animated: true)
}
```